# configuring Splunk for usability

Tags: splunk

I'm trying to work with Splunk, and it's uncomfortable for me. Having worked with log files for plenty of years, the Splunk approach is pretty awkward to me. So I'm trying to configure it for me to enable productive working. So far I couldn't find anything concerning these issues:

- how can I remove line breaks and get a horizontal scroll bar instead?
- how can I increase the pagination size to something reasonable like 1k or 10k?
- how can I disable the alternating row colors?
- is there something like "tail -f"?

So far my best approach for the first 3 questions is downloading the query and using a text editor, but it feels like I'm missing something there.

Comment: Q: Is there something like "tail -f"?
A: Yes, from the Time input, select Real-time to view events as they arrive for indexing

Comment: Sounds like you need to check out the *free* Splunk Fundamentals 1 self-paced class: https://www.splunk.com/en_us/training/free-courses/splunk-fundamentals-1.html

Answer (score 1):

> how can I remove line breaks and get a horizontal scroll bar instead?

No idea what you're asking here.

> how can I increase the pagination size to something reasonable like 1k or 10k?

What makes you think "1k or 100k" is "reasonable"? Splunk caps the number of displayed results per page at 100. There is no "workaround" beyond downloading the results into a CSV (or similar), and playing with it outside Splunk.

But why would you *do* that on anything that resembles a routine basis? Splunk is exceptionally powerful and data manipulation and visualization.

> how can I disable the alternating row colors?

What row colors? The ones that come up in the search window when you use [`| table`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/table) or [`| stats`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/stats)? You don't. Not unless you push the query to a [Dashboard Panel](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Viz/WorkingWithDashboardPanels), and play with the CSS for that dashboard.

> is there something like "tail -f"?

The closest option to something like this is a [realtime search](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Search/Specifyrealtimewindowsinyoursearch). However, use real-time searching with extreme caution, as it's *very* taxing on the environment

#### If you haven't done it yet

Go take the *free* Splunk Fundamentals 1 class: https://www.splunk.com/en_us/training/free-courses/splunk-fundamentals-1.html

Many of the questions you're likely having (or about to have) are covered in it

Comment: sorry, I asked this question in a moment where I was highly frustrated. I couldn't find solutions to my problems. But despite the fact that I expected no answers to exist, I still asked. That was wrong. Splunk is a great tool when you exactly know what to search for. But in situations where you don't know yet what to search for, I guess downloading into a text file is the way to go. I hoped for Splunk to have integrated support for that.

Comment: @EasterBunnyBugSmasher - you can do all *kinds* of 'fuzzy' searches ... really depends on your data :)    ...what kind of logs are you importing? Are they being well-parsed by your `props.conf`? Do you understand regex well? There's nothing that says you *have* to use fieldnames (though they're [generally] faster) - there's also `TERM()`, raw text strings, and more

Comment: it's more like "another system was unavailable, how well and how fast did we recover?", "when did this log message become so common and what happened before that?", "what happened between server starting and server being fully up?". I find it hard to create filters and searches for that. Browsing through the log is my preferred approach. And I'm a visual guy, I see things, but not when there is line breaks and such.

Comment: @EasterBunnyBugSmasher - those use cases are *literally* the bread-and-butter of Splunk :) ...setting up Alerts, etc to see things as (or slightly before) they happen.